# Alternatives to an array of T swift

Tags: swift

In my Quiz app I initialize quizzes, and the providing class does not know the format of the questions before being provided them (although they are constrained by a QuestionProtocol):

```
public protocol QuestionProtocol {
    init?(fields: [String] )
    var description: String {get}
    var question: String {get}
    var solution: String {get}
    var explainAnswer: String {get}
    var answered: Int {get set}
    var qa: String {get}
    var qb: String {get}
    var qc: String {get}
    var qd: String {get}
}
```

And I can initialize the quizzes and return them easily enough through a method with the signature

```
public func initializeQuizzes<T: QuestionProtocol>(with type: T.Type, withCompletionHandler completion: ((Result<[Quiz<T>], Error>) -> Void)?)
```

However to provide these quizzes is expensive (an API call or a SQL retrieval) so I want to store these quizzes and retrieve them separately from a suitable function with signature

```
public func getNextQFromSet<T: QuestionProtocol>(with type: T.Type) -> (question: T, answers: [String])?
```

The problem I have is storing these questions which are of type T.

They are linked to a Quiz object:

```
public class Quiz<T> {
    private let questions : [T]
    private let name : String

    init(name: String, questions: [T]) {
        self.name = name
        self.questions = questions
    }

    public func getQuestions() -> [T] {
        return questions
    }

    func getName() -> String {
        return name
    }
}
```

So I'm able to store them as quizzes that conform to the QuestionProtocol

```
private var quizzes = [Quiz<QuestionProtocol>]()
```

But then I lose the extra information I want to store in the question.

I can store Any, but I believe that is bad practice

```
private var anyquizzes = [Quiz<Any>]()
```

Ideally I would like to store T i.e.

```
Quiz<T>
```

but that seems to be impossible in Swift.

Because these classes are in a pod they have no way of knowing about the internal workings of a Question, and are provided these at runtime hence the use of generics and the difficulties in storing these questions.

I can't think of a way to improve the design of the App (more specifically the Pod) - I want to initialize the quizzes once and once only and then run functions like getNextQFromSet() to retrieve a relevant question - which obviously depends on me knowing the type of the question (which I do not know before runtime).

For clarity here is a link to the Pod: https://github.com/stevencurtis/QuizManager

How can I store an array containing these questions without knowing the type?

Comment: The type is the collection of fields that make up a question. The UI requests that the manager uses that type for the calculation.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. There is a separate pod that handles the business logic of the app. View controllers know nothing about the models, or the business logic. Obviously they have to interface, but SOLID is not the issue here (and certainly not the question) - the issue is that I can't store generic types in an array.

Comment: It's an entirely different section of the App, there is no UI and I do not want this QuizMaster pod to know about the underlying type as it is reusable for all questions that follow the protocol above. For clarity here is a link to the Pod: https://github.com/stevencurtis/QuizManager

Comment: Can you show us an example of a real question, with thoses "extra information" you are talking about?

Comment: @rraphael I refer you to the GitHub link that contains the entire background information including the entire question class (I repeat the link here: https://github.com/stevencurtis/QuizManager). Broadly, the extra information is simply fields in the question, but what they are are not relevant to the question as a generalized stackoverflow post could be generated not around this quiz context regarding storing generic data in an array.

Comment: If I keep only the "storing generics data" context then no, it's not possible, you have to use `Any`. And generics won't solve your issue because they are not resolved at runtime (as you seem to believe), but at compile time. If you want something resolvable at runtime, you must use `Any`. An exemple of a real question might not be relevant, but relying that much on the runtime in Swift is pretty much a bad practice as you said. I was just trying to understand what you are trying to achieve with this.

Comment: The idea is that you have a question database as an SQLite file. The format that you require from that database might differ, so when you provide a database file you also need to provide the format of the question that you require. So we process the database according to the format you require, and this is a use of generics.

Comment: I don't believe generics are resolved at runtime (a strange, and insulting inference from a question about how to solve a real world problem). It is rather this issue that I'm attempting to find a good solution for - I have an array of object (Any), and at runtime I know the type (from the user of the API). Using Any is a rather poor solution, but it does indeed work and is included here as an example.

Comment: I've looked at the GitHub repository. Is it possible to change to model to only use generics when you need to decode quizzes from the database and otherwise use `QuestionProtocol`. If not, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be short, I think it makes sense to remove `QuestionProtocol` and replace it with plain data structure `struct Question`.

Before I explain my point of view, I want to note that even though I looked at the pod, I still do not know all the requirements, so I might be wrong.

Let's try to have a look at the problem from design perspective instead of programming language perspective.

What is the reason of having `QuestionProtocol`? Could it be replaced with, let's say, object instead? Why do those properties should be polymorphic? Of course implementation details should be hidden, but hiding data is not about protocols or additional function layers, is about abstractions.

Let's convert `QuestionProtocol` to `Question` object for now and think about an abstraction. If there is a real abstraction, then there should an object that hides the data (details) and expose functions that manipulate that data. But there is no functions in `Question` object and it means that there is no real abstraction behind.

Finally, It means that `Question` entity most likely is a plain data structure with public properties and could be defined as `struct Question`.

Having this `Question` struct now, you can define quizzes as `Quiz<Question>` and use it to save and retrieve the data.

In addition, I think it worth to point out two things which could simplify and potentially improve design and implementation:

1. Why does `SQLiteManager` knows something about concrete question (depends on `QuestionProtocol`)? I think it makes sense to introduce some generic `DBObject` or at least plain dictionary `[String: Any]` which `SQLiteManager` would know how process and then insert. Then `Repository` could transform `Question` data structure into `DBObject` on some level of composition and pass it to `SQLiteManager`.
2. When using generics, in most cases there is no need to define additional `type: T.Type` parameter. Once generic is defined you can use it as `[T]`, `T.init`, etc. If you still need a metatype (`T.Type`) you can get by `T.self`.

Hope this helps!

**Update:**

There is great example of Quiz app created with TDD and modular design: [Quiz App](https://github.com/essentialdevelopercom/quiz-app). There is also a [video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GuxiFOiGtYk&list=PLyjgjmI1UzlSUlaQD0RvLwwW-LSlJn-F6) explaining design and creation process step by step.

Comment: Thanks for the additional points. I removed any concrete classes from SQLiteManager, but have chosen to leave T to be bound by the protocol to allow access to the specific fields that that gives visibility to.

Comment: You are welcome! Sorry, but I don't get your point regarding protocol. But, as I already said, most likely you do not need the protocol. Having simple Question DTO is what your POD could expose to consumers. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

> How can I store an array containing these questions without knowing
>   the type?

To my knowledge you can't. As [rraphael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3256795/rraphael) pointed out in his comment generics aren't resolved at runtime. Furthermore [Arrays](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) in swift are designed to hold a single type:

> Specifically, you use the Array type to hold elements of a single type, the array’s Element type.

So whatever you do you'll have either an array of `Any` or maybe `QuestionProtocol` but nothing more dynamic than that : **the type will be resolved at compilation time**

You may be able to redesign your `QuestionProtocol` to suit your needs but without any information on the different types of question it's a bit difficult to help you more since it is an architecture matter.

Comment: The different questions are simply what you might like to display. You might have a question format that has multiple answers and this is processed by the class (in the GitHub link), and we use the same class to perform this processing. This generic class accepts this format as the target format to output, but unfortunately we wish to store this within our class. Storing as Any, or even QuestionProtocol is quite unsatisfactory since when we return these we would need to then cast to our requested type (by storing the type requested, or just return the Base class).

Comment: If your questions may have multiple answers your `QuestionProtocol` could have an array of answers (and you might also want to create a type for your answers).

Comment: This is the issue with asking for concrete examples all the time. Yes, I'm aware of arrays. But the question is about having multiple types of questions (an example could be the number of answers, another might be the presence of an image). I'm aware how to store images - the question is about using generics to store an unknown type of question (concretely) - but more generally this is about storing a group of types without using Any.

Comment: Yes and my answer still stands you'll have to find another way. So if you already aware of alternatives, go ahead ;)

Comment: If I understand your solution is to store Any or maybe use QuestionProtocol. These were in the question (the Bounty mentions "Requires a solution that is NOT storing Any") so, yes I am aware of the alternatives that I wrote. So thank you, I will find another way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use enum with associated values for describing types. For example:

```
struct QuestionTypeA { }
struct QuestionTypeB { }
struct QuestionTypeC { }

enum Question {
    case typeA(question: QuestionTypeA)
    case typeB(question: QuestionTypeB)
    case typeC(question: QuestionTypeC)
}
```

And then:

```
public class Quiz {
    private let questions : Question
    private let name : String
    ...
```

And store an array of Quiz without generic

```
private var anyquizzes = [Quiz]()
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to store a `Quiz<T>` and a `Quiz<U>` in the same array using either of those types.  They're just not the same type.

If you have an `Array<QuizProtocol>`, you can just match against your known types in a switch-case statement:

```
var quizzes: [QuizProtocol] = ...

for quiz in quizzes {
    switch quiz {
       case let someQuiz as SomeQuiz:
           ...
       case let someOtherQuiz as SomeOtherQuiz:
           ...
       default: 
           ... // couldn't cast to any known type; do some fallback logic
       ....
    }
}
```

where SomeQuiz and SomeOtherQuiz conform to QuizProtocol (though strictly speaking, you could match against any type).